# exception here in hbm.xml

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

```
<generator class="increment" />
    <id name="id" />
    <property name="movie"  />
    <property name="showtimes" />
    <property name="seatno" />
</class>
```

```
Exception
ERROR: HHH000196: Error parsing XML (2) : The content of element type "class" must match "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,fetch-profile*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)".

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.legacyReadMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:516)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:512)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:686)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:769)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2255)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2227)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2207)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2160)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2075)
    at test.ClientUsingAssigned.main(ClientUsingAssigned.java:16)
```

Comment: Please provide the full XML file .

Comment: <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    
<hibernate-mapping>
    
   <class name="beans.BookMovie" table="tbook" schema="system">
   
    <generator class="increment" />
        <id name="id" />
        <property name="movie"  />
        <property name="showtimes" />
        <property name="seatno" />
    </class>
   
</hibernate-mapping>

Comment: Uh...in the question, not as a comment!

Answer (score 0):

Use `<generator>` tag inside `<Id>`

```
  <hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the employee detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="increment"/>
      </id>
      <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="salary" column="salary" type="int"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: which database You are using ?

Comment: Try to use native instead of increment,some database does not support increment